# Atomic update in Mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose, passport.js, atomic

I want to let users of my app increment `value` one time only. The following code fails, because `update` in mongoose is asynchronous. My check `if(user.valueIncremented)` fails for the next consecutive requests to this api, because the `valueIncremented`isn't updated at this point, but it will be on the next event loop. So, what do I do, good sirs?

```js
var Account = new Schema({
 _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 value: {type: Number, default: 0},
 valueIncremented: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

router.post('/incrementValue', function(req, res, next) {
 var user = req.user;
 if(user.valueIncremented) {
  return next();
 }
 else {
  incrementValue();
 }
 function incrementValue(){
  var condition = {
   _id: user._id;
  }
  var update = {
   $inc: {
    value: 1
   },
   $set: {
    valueIncremented: true
   }
  }
  Account.update(condition, update).exec();
 }
})
```

Comment: Where are you setting req.user.valueIncremented? And how is it exactly failing?

Answer (score 0):

Here I've added an additional query to the database. Now when I do two or more consective calls to this api, `value` is incremented one time only.

```js
router.post('/incrementValue', function(req, res, next) {
 var id = req.user._id;
 Account.findById(id).exec(function(err, user){
  if(err) {
   return next(err);
  }
  if(user.valueIncremented) {
   return next();
  }
  else {
   incrementValue();
  }
  function incrementValue(){
   var condition = {
    _id: id
   }
   var update = {
    $inc: {
     value: 1
    },
    $set: {
     valueIncremented: true
    }
   }
   Account.update(condition, update).exec();
  }  
 })
})
```